# BUG Xorg, I see black shadows in Unreal Engine

Tags: archlinux, unreal-engine4

i am beginner in Unreal Engine. o i have installed the mesa, xf86-video-intel, but when i start an project, i see black "shadows" who follow my move in the scene. I am on Arch Linux( 4.10.13-1-ARCH )

Sorry for my bad english, i am french ^^ Good day !
[image: Unreal Engine]

Comment: Have you tried to post it on answerhub?
https://answers.unrealengine.com/spaces/11/bugs-and-crashes.html

Comment: The french documentation is poor compared to the english one. I hope you followed https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics and especially https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Xorg_configuration